# Simple Knowledge Base (database with web frontend) with API

Tags: open-source, web-apps, database, api, knowledge-base

Are there simple knowledge base (or just database with simple web-frontend) with HTTP API, especially API for searching items.

Idea is to

- fill that base with some data with that simple interface (by human);
- access that data by API (by robot).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please indicate if you are lokking for, say, a notes-app, or a semantic-web solution, or a relational database, or something else entirely. For all of the 3 different examples I've mentioned, there are various free software, and commercial products available.

Comment: Check if [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org) or [Turtl](https://turtlapp.com) might be able to fit your use case – both are open-source so you might be able to adjust them to your needs.